# Handle boto3 timestamp on string type with offset

Tags: python, boto3, aws-codecommit

I'm using boto3 [UserInfo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_UserInfo.html) to get the information related to some AWS CodeCommit commits, and I'm trying to calculate the days between the output of the `date` field and the current date. But the issue is that this field output is something like:

```
1685369892 +0000
```

And `type` gives me `<class 'str'>.`

So if I want to do something like

```
datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()) - DateFieldFromCodeCommit
```

I receive:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

So, if the output of that date field is a string I want to know how to convert to a datetime or similar format in order to calculate with other dates. Thanks